# Converting object to array (angularjs and typeahead)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have an object that looks like this: 
    {"1": "2", "3": "4"}

I don't have direct access to this data, so when I bring it in via ajax how can I convert it to an array? Like so:
    [{"1": "2"}, {"3": "4"}]

PS: I'm using this output data in an angular-ui typeahead which dislikes objects and only likes strings.

Comment: So you want to turn an object into an array of objects with each element representing a property?'

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right

Comment: u can try this way 
$scope.arrayList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Object));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a snippet:

```
var inputObj = {'1': '2', '3': '4'};
var output = [];
for (var key in inputObj) {
  // must create a temp object to set the key using a variable
  var tempObj = {};
  tempObj[key] = inputObj[key];
  output.push(tempObj);
}

console.log(output);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What does the [key] refer to?

Comment: When you use a `for` loop to iterate over an object, it actually iterates over the keys (as in key/value pairs) of the object as the index.  You can then use the key to get the value from the object using the index notation `myObject[key]`.  For example, for an object `{'myKey': 'myValue'}`, you can get the key from the object via `myObject['myKey']`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @matenji:  I made a slight typo in that comment -- I meant:  

For example, for an object {'myKey': 'myValue'}, you can get the **value** from the object via myObject['myKey'].

Comment: I get it, so what if you just want the value of myValue?

Comment: @matenji:  In this example, the value of the object *is* "myValue", so you would get it by using `myObject['myKey']`.  That example is a little confusing because the values look like variable names.  Here's a less confusing example:
    `var employee = {'firstName': 'Steve', 'lastName': 'Davis'};
    console.log('First name is: ' + employee['firstName']);`
That would print "First name is Steve".